# c# byte order in a byte array?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, endianness

I have an array of bytes representing a picture(bgra).
I'd like to know which is the order for the bytes in a c# byte[].
Are the bytes represented in little or big endian ?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Ask BitConverter.IsLittleEndian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke's is right but ii wonder if one could write code to prove it (wihout BitConvert.IsLittleEndian )

```
ushort word = 0x0001;  // 16bit word with lsb set
var bits = new BitArray(BitConvert.GetBytes());

if (bits[0]) {
    // little endian
} else if (bits[8]) { 
    // big endian
}
```

**edit for Sinatr**

Comment: I like it, its a really clean proof

Comment: I thought endian is something to do with `bytes`, not bits. Can you please elaborate? I would try to store a word (which has only low byte set) somehow and then read it as a byte array and see if the first byte is zero or not.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is little endian, so if you are running c# you are probably using little endian

Comment: Okay thanks, but then is it possible to swap the order to big Endian(it may be a very stupid questino but i have a problem with picture represention and i think it come from the order in a byte array).

Comment: This answer doesn't help. It doesn't depend on C#, but on the origin of the byte array. You could use both (little or big endian) in C#.

Comment: Check out here for how to reverse endianness in c# http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/144b3047-bcbd-48d6-a28a-6fbda82e151e